# Add Version Definition File URL in Ambari web UI

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, ambari

I'm trying to create a cluster in Ambari web UI.
[Create cluster web UI (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pugQO.png)

I reach a point where I need to put Version Definition File URL.
[Add version (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G5Yq.png)

Where can I find this URL, without being from cloudera?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a cluster services stack that define what Ambari will install and manage.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/How-To+Define+Stacks+and+Services

One popular open-source version of services that can be used with Ambari is Apache BigTop